# Writing String to text file in C leaves bits of characters off

Tags: c, text-files

My goal is to be able to write a string to a file and have the whole thing show up, and not just part of it. The problem is that when i check into my text file there is a few charters left off of the string that i typed in.

Here is My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char comment[100];
    fp=fopen("/home/matthew/Desktop/BBE.txt","w");
    printf("Enter, String: ");
    scanf("%s", &comment);
    fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
    fputs(comment,fp); 
}
```

And the input that i want in my text file is this:

```
Enter, String: Hello World
```

But when i check my text file i get this:

```
 World
```

I am missing a word here and have no idea why, please help.

Comment: Make up your mind: `scanf` or `fgets`. These are alternative ways of reading strings. (You want to read a line that contains spaces, so keep the `fgets` and delete the `scanf`.)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the scanf, as it is reading in the first word of your input, so your code looks like this:

```
char comment[100];
fp=fopen("/home/matthew/Desktop/BBE.txt","w");
printf("Enter, String: ");
fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
fputs(comment,fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the input from the user using both fgets and scanf. You don't need both. Also, in your scanf, you are passing the address of the address of the first element of the character array instead of just the address of the first element (use 'comment' instead of '&comment' in your scanf). You are also not closing the File after write. Try following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

FILE *fp = fopen("/home/matthew/Desktop/BBE.txt", "w");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
char comment[100];
fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
printf("Enter, String: ");
scanf("%s", comment); //Don't pass &comment. Just pass 'comment' - the addr of zeroth element.
//fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
fputs(comment,fp);
fclose(fp);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why are you using two files here when you've to write the input from stdin in one of the file? Below piece of code will help you get the desired output. Better to use gets() here instead of fgets() as you're not reading input from file. Also, don't forget to close the files when you're done. Hope this helps!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    char comment[100] = {0};
     fp=fopen("tempfile.txt","w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter String: ");
    gets(comment);
    fwrite(comment, sizeof(comment), 1, fp) ;

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```